# how to login from non-global zone to global zone in solaris 10

Tags: solaris

how to login from non-global zone to global zone in Solaris 10. I can login to the non-global zone from putty. I do not know the hostname of the global zone.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't known how to login through the network, i.e. if you don't know the name or IP address of your global zone, there is no way, no shortcut.

This is by design and for obvious security reasons. Zones are isolated from each other and from the global zone. Only the global zone has full power to access the non global zones.